# Visa questions regarding post-covid Vietnam

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, vietnam, e-visas, visa-runs

I am travelling to Vietnam in August and I am trying to figure out the visa rules for the country, which have changed quite a bit from the last time I was there ~7 years ago, but so far I'm failing.

I am from Sweden and due to this I can stay for 15 days in Vietnam without a visa, and if I wish to stay longer the option exists to apply for an e-visa that allows me to stay for 30 days, single entry.

The issue is that I wish to stay in Vietnam for 30 days, but require a multiple entry visa, since I plan a short excursion to Bali for a few days and then back to Vietnam.

So what I would want is some type of multiple entry visa, but I can't find any good way to apply for one.

The Vietnamese embassy in my country gives some vague advice that I should contact a Vietnamese resident in Vietnam who should then apply for me from inside Vietnam, after which I can pick up a visa on arrival at the airport, but this seems to be both a hassle and a little bit sketchy (I'd much, much rather have things completed in advance, this will be quite an expensive trip).

The best plan I can figure out at the moment is to apply for a 30-day e-visa and set the date of entry to when I arrive in Vietnam from Bali, after that trip is completed. Then I arrive in Vietnam, use my visa-exemption of 15 days, leave for Bali, and return using my 30-day e-visa.

Is this a feasible plan, or will there be hindrances I haven't thought of, like some sort of re-entry ban if you leave Vietnam and return within a few days?

Anyone who is knowledgeable regarding visa-rules in general, or more hopefully about Vietnam in particular, that can chime in? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: "I arrive in Vietnam, use my visa-exemption of 15 days, leave for Bali, and return using my 30-day e-visa." <-- this will workout smoothly. 

Worry about MEV only if you want to be in Vietnam thrice in less than 30d

Answer (score 0):

> The Vietnamese embassy in my country gives some vague advice that I should contact a Vietnamese resident in Vietnam who should then apply for me from inside Vietnam, after which I can pick up a visa on arrival at the airport, but this seems to be both a hassle and a little bit sketchy (I'd much, much rather have things completed in advance, this will be quite an expensive trip).

This is the [pre-arranged visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/101630/118049) process. For this, you need an official invitation letter from a person/company in Vietnam. There are some agencies that will do that for individuals for a fee.

With the advantage of it being multiple-entry if wanted. A random online agency quoted US$20 for a 1-month multiple entry.

You can see this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/34669/118049) about those